# React: render() and multiple children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a map component that's out of my control that renders all of it's direct children:

```
<map>
  <point />
  <circle />
  <circle />
</map>
```

Now I'm trying to write a component that returns multiple objects:

```
<myComponent>
  <circle />
  <circle />
</myComponent>
```

And drop it into my map:

```
<map>
  <point />
  <circle />
  <circle />
  <myComponent>
    <circle />
    <circle />
  </myComponent>
</map>
```

But as the map only renders *direct* children, I'm not sure how to get this to work.  Help?

Comment: You might want to elaborate more on your questions... What did you try and what's happening... Where is the map component from? Are the children of map component exposed as API?

Comment: What do you mean by "a component that returns"...could you more elaborate?

Comment: Simple case -- I'm just trying to get 2 `<circle />`s lifted from my component to the map

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong, I guess this is what you are looking for.

```
function MyComponent (props) {
  const objs = props.objs;
  const listItems = objs.map((obj) =>
    < {obj} />
  );
  return (
    <map>{listItems} </map>
  );
}

const objs = ['circle', 'circle'];
ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent objs={objs} />, //pass children i.e.,objs as props to the MyComponent
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: lol, yeah.  Not sure why I was trying to force it to be a react component, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the special [`children` prop](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx):

```
function myComponent(props) {
  return (
    <map>
      {props.children}
    </map>
  );
}
```

And then use it in another component as you normally would:

```
...
render() {
  return (
    <myComponent>
      <circle />
      <circle />
    </myComponent>
  );
}
...
```

Comment: this only works if there's only one instance of `myComponent` though, correct?

Comment: no, that should never be a limiting factor. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Oh, I see the confusion, sorry.  I just edited the original question, that should clarify I hope

Comment: I'm afraid it does not clarify. Please edit the question to include some code examples.

Answer (score 0):

React 16 introduced Fragments
so you can do

```
...
render() {
  return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <circle />
    <circle />
  </React.Fragment>
  );
}
...
```